# Google IMA3 sdk , which is best video player to use android

Tags: android, google-dfp, vast, video-ads

I am new to work with `Google IMA3 SDK` for displaying video ads througt `DFP`, I just went through [Quick start IMA android](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/quickstart) , it says I can use [Google Media Framework (GMF)](https://github.com/googleads/google-media-framework-android) **OR** `Android Videoview`

**Android Videoview**

This is not customised to work with `Google IMA3` , as far as I know , I have to do extra work with is player for **pre-roll , mid-roll & post-roll** concept.

**Google Media Framework (GMF)**

The Google Media Framework (GMF) is a lightweight media player designed to make video playback and integration with the Google IMA SDK on Android easier. **BUT this is still in `beta` version . There are still quite OPEN ISSUES**

This [IMA3: Video technology partners](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/186110) , in this link they say I can use any of them , **Are they OPEN SOURCE**.

**I am still confused what to do**